# IAP Auto-Renewable Subscription not visible

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am trying to add IAP in my iOS app through iTunes Connect (Admin access). Reference to screenshot attached, I am able to View Shared Secret but I am not getting Auto-Renewable Subscription listed under the IAP options available. I did check for all the agreements and all of them are updated. Am I missing something here? Will I be able to add Auto-Renew purchases only after my App goes live?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Sign in to your iTunes Connect account.
2. Click Agreements, Tax, and Banking.
3. Under Request Contracts, click Request for the iOS Paid Applications contract type.
4. After you review the agreement, check I have read and agree to the agreement presented above and click Submit.

Plus you should generate a secret key, at the InApp purchase section.

Answer (score 0):

Since, this Auto-Renewable Subscription option has been moved under Subscriptions. You'll want to create your Subscription group first, then click into it in order to make the new Auto-Renewable Subscription.

Here's more on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73273034/4968696