# App Store Connect - In App Purchase creation not allowing Auto Renewable Subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am starting to set up in App Purchases for my app. I need to create a Auto Renewable subscription. However when I go to App Store Connect / my app / In-App Purchases and click on create. The only options available in the type field are Consumable and Non Consumable.
Here is the screen shot:

[image]

I haven't been able to find any reason for this. There are no outstanding agreements to accept in the financials, taxes and payment screens.

If any one could let me know what I am missing here or doing incorrectly, I would really appreciate it.
Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using a wrong menu item. Instead of "In-App Purchases", go to "Subscriptions" to create an auto-renewable subscription.

[image]